# Without graphing, can we determine the two values of b that will identify the lines needed to form these 2 congruent triangles.

Tags: geometry

> Each of 2 congruent triangles has area of 24 square units; Their
>   vertices are determined by the intersection of the lines with
>   equations $$y = -4$$ $$x = 0$$ $$y = -0.75x + b$$
>
> Without graphing it out, can we determine the two values of b that
>   will identify the lines needed to form these triangles.

Well, without graphing it out I find it hard to solve such a question. I only can do it when I drew it out and deduced that $$\frac{1}{2}\left((b+4) \times (\frac{4}{3}b + \frac{16}{3})\right)= 24$$ and proceed to solve the equation to get b = 2, -10.

I would appreciate a simple enough solution such that middle schoolers can understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates of the triangle's vertices are:

$$y=-4, x=0 \Rightarrow (0, -4)$$

$$x=0, y=0.75x+b \Rightarrow (0, b)$$

and when $y=-0.75x+b, y=-4$:

$$-\frac{3}{4}x+b=-4 \Rightarrow x= -\frac{4}{3} (-4-b)=\frac{16}{3}+\frac{4}{3}b$$

so the coordinate of the vertex is $\left(\frac{16}{3}+\frac{4}{3}b, -4 \right)$.

Therefore, the height of the triangle is $|b-(-4)|$ and the width of the base is $\frac{16}{3} + \frac{4}{3}b$, which is the same as your method.

---

We can compute the answer more efficiently as well: we have $\frac{1}{2} bh = 24$ so: $$bh = 48 \Rightarrow \frac{b}{h} \cdot h^2 = \frac{1}{h/b} h^2 =48$$

$\frac{h}{b}$ is equal to the absolute value of the slope (rise over run), since the height and the base must be a positive number. We also found that the height is $|b-(-4)|$, so we get:

$$\frac{1}{3/4} \cdot|b-(-4)|^2  = 48$$
$$(b+4)^2 = 36$$

and this results in $b=2,-10$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try to use the formulae for area of triangle given the co-ordinate of vertices. The co-ordinates come out to be $(0 , -4)$ , $(0 , b)$ and $((4+b)/0.75 , -4)$

Using , 
$
\Delta = 1/2 * [(x_1-x_2)*y_3 + (x_2-x_3)*y_1 + (x_3-x_1)*y_2] = 24
$

$
0 + 4*(4+b)/0.75 + b*(4+b)/0.75 = 48
$

$
(4+b) ^ 2 = 36 
$

$
4 + b = 6 , 4+b = -6
$

$
b = 2 , b = -10 
$

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to the one I had in other forum only whose link is.  https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/discussion-forum/topic/y-intercept-of-line/?part=1#postid-145.
Only difference is instead of one of side as X axis your question has is y=-4. Using area of triangle as half base into height. We can find b.
Three vertices are (0,-4) , (0,b), and $(\frac{4}{3}(b+4),-4)$
$$ Area = (\frac{1}{2})((\frac{4}{3})(b+4))(b+4)=24$$
$$\therefore (b+4)^2=36$$
$$\Rightarrow b+4=\pm 6$$

Comment: how can we know that $b$ is not negative though? Is absolute $b$ needed?

Comment: Use modules with (b+4).

Comment: For better understanding you can check the link given .